# Proper configuration for Spring Cloud Stream Application - load-generator-source

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to test some performance of Spring Cloud Stream Applications (https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications), specifically publishing. So I saw that there was a `load-generator-source` and that seems perfect for my needs.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make it run. I followed the build instructions on the project page. It successfully built the apps and functions. Then I went to build the actual load generator app using the following:

```
cd apps/load-generator-source-rabbit
./mvnw clean package
cd target
java -jar load-generator-source-rabbit-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The build was successful.
When I run, I ultimately get the following:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'load-generatorSupplier' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'load-generatorSupplier' in your configuration.
```

This is where I am stuck. In `load-generator-source/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/source/load/generator/LoadGeneratorSourceConfiguration.java` there is the following:

```
@Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<?>>> loadGeneratorSupplier() {
        return () -> processor;
    }
```

Isn't that the bean it says I am missing?

I am hoping someone can help as I am quite lost here ;)

Cheers

Comment: Did you try the app from maven central?If its broken, let us know, this might be some configuration issues, we will fix in that case. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/load-generator-source-rabbit/3.0.2/

Comment: This ran. I am not sure of next steps. I actually want to run this against the Solace binder so the prebuilt apps won't help. If I try and build according to the build instructions, I get my OP.

Comment: Ok, we will take a look to see what's going on with the snapshots.

Comment: @sobychacko I believe I have it working now. It builds and runs both with the Rabbit binder and also the Solace binder. I believe I was having an issue building the Functions and it failed at the Protobuf dependency on `libAtomic1`. I added that and the functions built ok.

Comment: I guess the question now is... how do I actually generate load? It isn't connecting to a queue.

Comment: There are some issues in the way this app is configured. Please see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are some issues in the load-generator-source app that is shipped with the apps. We will address the problems in the next release. In the meantime, you can get this source works by doing something similar to the following.

```
java -jar load-generator-source-rabbit-3.0.2.jar --spring.cloud.function.definition=loadGeneratorSupplier --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.loadGeneratorSupplier-out-0.destination=load-gen-test
```

Basically, the property `spring.cloud.function.definition` was getting populated with a wrong value - `load-generatorSupplier` instead of `loadGeneratorSupplier`. This is auto generated by the plugin that generates the binder app. We will address this soon, but in the meantime, you can use the above workaround as an alternative if that is an option for you.

Comment: I tested using the suggestion above and now it does connect to my Solace binder and publish the load-generator messages. Thanks a lot for your help. @sobychacko

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to override default name

```
@Bean("load-generatorSupplier")
public Supplier<Flux<Message<?>>> loadGeneratorSupplier() {
        return () -> processor;
}
```

Comment: this did not work. I changed it and rebuilt and the runtime error persists